# How to use Unity Toggle Check Function (checked and unchecked)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, toggle, oncheckedchanged

I'm trying to toggle. When I click on the toggle (if it is on I mean checked), it closes some gameobject, if I click on the toggle (if it is off I mean unchecked) it opens some gameobject but I don't know which function unity
`toggle.onselect`?
`toggle.onValuesChanged`? or others which one

```
public GameObject controlledObject;
public NamesGet nameController;
public Text text;
public Button button;
public Toggle toggle;
private bool deneme;
public void FixedUpdate()
{
    text.text = controlledObject.name;

    if(?????????)
    {
        controlledObject.SetActive(!controlledObject.activeSelf);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use something like this :

```
toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) =>
    {
        MyListener(value);
   });//Do this in Start() for example

public void MyListener(bool value)
{
 if(value)
    {
    //do the stuff when the toggle is on
    }else {
    //do the stuff when the toggle is off
    }

}
```

Comment: if i use your code , unity send me to this error :
The best overloaded method match for 'UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent<bool>.AddListener(UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<bool>)' has some invalid arguments



i write this code: 
toggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(MyListener);

Comment: @Nurullah I changed my answer so that it works. I tested it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

New
instead using OnValueChanged why not use EventTrigger - Pointer Click so it will only be called Once.
same as adding Listener via script but its more quick and handy.